# Spring Cloud Native Config Server not picking yml files

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

My Spring cloud config server not picking the yml files from class path

```
    spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
       native:
            search-locations: file:///C:/Users/Arun/git/MicroService_sample/config-server/src/main/resources/application-local.yml
```

getting below result , result remains same even if i use `search-locations: classpath:/configserver-local.yml`

result

```
  {"name":"configserver","profiles":["local"],"label":null,"version":"d1da013b1365b9001a5609e12c8590c875d782f4","state":null,"propertySources":[]}
```

Endpoint : http://localhost:8080/configserver/local

and i don't find any logs for picking yml file while application start up

Comment: You need to give it a directory, not a file

Comment: @spencergibb yes i have tried that too .but result remains same.

Comment: I think you should go through the following documentation. [Core concepts of Spring Cloud](https://www.itechpeeps.com/2019/04/spring-cloud/) This documentation explained the key concepts very well.
It will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to modify your search-locations address

I tried put the file in D dish with .yml like below

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
       native:
            search-locations: D:/
```

and file in D:\configserver-local.yml with content

```
test: 1233333
```

and the result is expected when I access http://localhost:8080/configserver/local

```
{"name":"configserver","profiles":["local"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"file:D:/configserver-local.yml","source":{"test":1233333}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had a lot of troubles to set this search location in native mode with absolute path on Windows.

At the end, after a lot a research and tries, I chose to integrate the configuration files directly in the config-server classpath, in a "config" folder in the src/main/resources folder.

Since "native" mode is probably just for development and test environment (for production, I will use the normal mode, that reads for the Git repository and not the local hard drive), it is quite okay for me.

You already have followed what is in the document (you need 3 `/` after "file" since you are on Windows).
The only alternative that was working for me was to use the `user.home` directory, but I didn't want this directory, so I put the properties files in the src/main/resources/config folder.

Syntax for `user.home` directory:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:///${user.home}/Downloads/config-folder
```